# Amazon Dynamodb find All in grails

Tags: postgresql, grails, amazon-dynamodb, guava, throughput

I have a grails application. I'm using amazon dynamodb for a specific requirement which is accessed, and entries are added by a different application. Now I need to get all the information from the dynamodb table to a postgreSQL table. There are over 10000 records in the dynamodb but the throughput is

```
Read capacity units : 100
Write capacity units : 100
```

In BuildConfig.groovy I have defined the plugin

```
compile ":dynamodb:0.1.1"
```

In config.groovy I have the following configuration

```
grails {
  dynamodb {
    accessKey = '***'
    secretKey = '***'
    disableDrop = true
    dbCreate = 'create'
  }
}
```

The code I have looks something similar to this

```
class book {

  Long id
  String author
  String name
  date publishedDate

  static constraints = {
  }

  static mapWith = "dynamodb"
  static mapping = {
    table 'book'
    throughput read:100
  }
}
```

When I try something like book.findAll() I get the following error

```
AmazonClientException: Unable to unmarshall response (Connection reset)
```

And when I tried to reduce the number of records by trying something like book.findAllByAuthor() (which also wud have above 1000's of records) I get the following error

```
Caused by ProvisionedThroughputExceededException: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: AmazonDynamoDB, AWS Request ID: ***, AWS Error Code: ProvisionedThroughputExceededException, AWS Error Message: The level of configured provisioned throughput for the table was exceeded. Consider increasing your provisioning level with the UpdateTable API.
```

I have the need to get all the records in dynamodb despite the throughput restriction and save it in a postgres table. Is there a way to do so?

I'm very new to this area, thanks in advance for the help.

After some research I came Across Google Guava. But even to use Guava RateLimiter, there wont be a fixed number of times I would need to send the request of how long it would take. So I'm looking for a solution which will suit the requirement I have

Answer (score 0):

Probably your issue is not connected with grails at all. The returned error message claims: `The level of configured provisioned throughput for the table was exceeded. Consider increasing your provisioning level with the UpdateTable API`

So you should consider increasing level of throughput (for this option you have to pay more) or adjust your queries to obey actual limits.

Check out also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31484168/2166188

Comment: I'm looking for a solution which means I do not have to increase the throuhput, since it means I have to pay more. After a bit more researching, Throttling could be a solution for this, which wont exceed the limit just would take longer for task to complete.  I have not done that before, so help from that end would also be helpful.

Comment: First you should check out what are the limits which you are violating. For example you could create a job which will be executed every 15 minutes until it finish full task.

Comment: As I have described in the above sample, I require to get all the records from dynamodb to be processed. So I am violating the read capacity units. I'm looking for a solution where I would be able to use throttling to achieve my goal, which would take longer but will finish the task.