# Spring Aws Kinesis Binder ProvisionedThroughputExceededException while consuming messages in Batch Mode

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis, spring-cloud-aws, spring-integration-aws

I am using the batch mode to pull in the records from kinesis stream. We are using spring aws kinesis binder.

Most of the times we are not able to pull messages from stream. Only some times we are able to pull messages from stream.

My config looks like below

**My config**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kinesis:
        binder:
          locks:
            leaseDuration: 30
            readCapacity: 1
            writeCapacity: 1
          checkpoint:
            readCapacity: 1
            writeCapacity: 1
        bindings:
          InStreamGroupOne:
            consumer:
              listenerMode: batch
              idleBetweenPolls: 30000
              recordsLimit: 5000
              consumer-backoff: 1000
      bindings:
        InStreamGroupOne:
          group: in-stream-group
          destination: stream-1
          content-type: application/json
        OutboundStreamOne:
          destination: stream-2
          content-type: application/json
        OutboundStreamTwo:
          destination: stream-3
          content-type: application/json
        OutboundStreamThree:
          destination: stream-4
          content-type: application/json
```

When I enable the debug logging, I could able to see this exception

```
Received error response: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ProvisionedThroughputExceededException: The level of configured provisioned throughput for the table was exceeded. Consider increasing your provisioning level with the UpdateTable API. (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ProvisionedThroughputExceededException;
```

I tried reducing the batch size as 150 and idleBetweenPools to 1sec. I also updated readCapacity and writeCapacity to 10. But same error.

From AWS console, I could see that SpringIntegrationLockRegistry has crossed read threshold.

Can you please help us understand whats wrong.

It works some times and does not work some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do in regards to DynamoDB on AWS: [How to solve throughput error for dynamodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468379/how-to-solve-throughput-error-for-dynamodb)

From the application perspective, you can play with options for the locks: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-docs/src/main/asciidoc/overview.adoc#lockregistry

> `leaseDuration`
>
> The length of time that the lease for the lock will be granted for. If this is set to, for example, 30 seconds, then the lock will expire if the heartbeat is not sent for at least 30 seconds (which would happen if the box or the heartbeat thread dies, for example.)
>
> Default: 20
>
> `heartbeatPeriod`
>
> How often to update DynamoDB to note that the instance is still running (recommendation is to make this at least 3 times smaller than the leaseDuration - for example heartBeatPeriod=1 second, leaseDuration=10 seconds could be a reasonable configuration, make sure to include a buffer for network latency.)
>
> Default: 5
>
> `refreshPeriod`
>
> How long to wait before trying to get the lock again (if set to 10 seconds, for example, it would attempt to do so every 10 seconds)
>
> Default: 1000

Comment: Thank you. Will there be any improvement, if we change the tables of checkpoint and meta. Currently they are shared tables across other applications too?

Comment: Yes, I think so. The `read/write` capacities are really shared between table clients. But that's already not a Spring question. Consider to consult with AWS on the matter directly.  Or don't forget to mark the question in the future with an appropriate AWS tag, so their community will see the question and may respond or correct us if we are wrong some way.